# Routing LAN through proxy

Tags: routing, squid

I need help to route LAN address back to internal network via a Squid(Proxy) box.

How can I forward this traffic through SQUID with 2 interface?

I need this rule go from load balancer into eth0 and go out via eth1 and go back to firewall.

I did it by add a `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1` file

```
172.16.0.0/16 via 192.168.200.1 dev eth1
```

[image]